# Jquery - Make image switch depending on the direction user drags it

Tags: jquery, image, draggable

I am using JQuery and would like to do the following. I have 2 images of a car. One that faces left  and one that faces right (x-axis). When a user clicks and drags the car in a direction I want the image 
of the car to switch to be the one that faces in the same direction.

Here's what I have so far:

I have a DIV called #car that is assigned to this code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#car" ).draggable();
  });
```

and it drags just fine. I then have an image that is wrapped in the #car div called #myImage and the HTML code is as follows:

```
 <img id="myImage" src="" alt="" height="42" width="42" />
```

I then have the Jquery code that I am attempting to "connect" to #myImage below.

```
function carDirection(){
var currentPosition = $("#myImage").text(this.id + offset.left );
if ("#myImage" <= currentPosition){
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "leftCar.png");   
  }
  else {
    $("#myImage").attr("src", "rightCar.png");
  }
};
```

So to summarize and make this even clearer I am creating a div that is using JQuery's draggable effect and I simply want an image that is wrapped in it to change depending on if the user drags it left or right with the mouse. The image should stay the same after the user lets go of the mouse.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for a draggable image carousel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324690/jquery-ui-image-carousel-with-draggable-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `drag` callback for `.draggable()` to determine if the car has moved left or right since last time.

EDIT: Code updated to be a lot clearer with more comments.

[jsFiddle example is available](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/f7SVq/).

```
// defining custom object to hold images to use. 
// Change as required in actual code.
var sprites = {
    car: {
        left: 'http://placehold.it/200&text=Left',
        right: 'http://placehold.it/200&text=Right'
    }
};

$(function() {
    var carImage = document.getElementById('myImage'); // no need to use jQuery to get by ID
    $('#car').draggable({
        // define the behaviour to be run continually
        // whilst car is being dragged.
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            // get the last left position (think x co-ordinate)
            // of the thing you are dragging (the helper) 
            // using the jQuery data method, which stores
            // that info against the actual HTML element itself.
            // Note that if this is the first time the function is
            // run, there IS no such data, so the "|| thisX" ensures 
            // that there is a value the first time.
            var thisX = ui.offset.left,
                lastX = ui.helper.data('lastLeft') || thisX;
            if (thisX < lastX) {
                // must be moving left
                carImage.src = sprites.car.left;
            } 
            if (thisX > lastX) {
                // must be moving right
                carImage.src = sprites.car.right;
            }
            // don't do anything if the "x-coord" is the same
            // or else it causes flickering.

            // store the current position to compare with next time
            // this function is run.
            ui.helper.data('lastLeft', thisX);
        }
    });
});​
```

Note that you would be better to use CSS classes and a sprite image (a single image containing both left and right car images), as I believe changing the background position of the same image is faster for most browsers than changing the `src`. Also, you only need to load one image, and so you don't need to load the image for the other direction the first time it changes. Does that make sense?

Is there anything else from my code that doesn't make sense now?

Comment: The good part about this is that I completely copied and pasted your code and it worked! The bad part is I am new to programming and I don't understand it,  so now I feel obligated to abstain from the rest of my project until I do. Thank you much!

Comment: @Taoist No probs! To make the code a bit easier to understand, I redid it with a lot more comments, and made a jsFiddle example for you/others to play with. Let me know if it helps you understand better, and please accept this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I will look up image sprites.This is new to me. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var offset = $("#myImage").offset();
$("#myImage").draggable({
    drag: function() {
       var this_offset = $(this).offset();
       if(this_offset.left < offset.left) {
          $(this).attr('src','leftCar.png');
       } else {
          $(this).attr('src','rightCar.png');   
       }
    }
});​
```

I've included a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aD8S6/2/) using background-color instead of images.

Comment: I looked at the JsFiddle and the div doesn't change to anything except blue.

Comment: As I said, I've used changing background-colors to indicate left/right motion instead of background-image because I don't have access to your images

Comment: You've edited it since my comment. I see that it works. Thank you!

Comment: Jamie: The problem with your code is that it looks at the initial position to determine if the car has moved left or right. I believe that @Taoist wanted it to consider the direction the user is dragging it in "at the time", not relative to the original position. Hence you need to do what I did in my answer and store the offset each time to compare to.